# Using Storyboards with UIViewControllers that do not have UITableViews

Tags: iphone, uistoryboard

I watched the WWDC tutorial on using storyboards, and can see the benefit if you're using tableviews, but I can't quite see how you would use them otherwise.

For example, if I am using a MKMapView, and I present a pin, and a callout for that pin, if I want to go to my next view controller, as far as I know, I have to go to the next detail view controller in code and cannot use a storyboard or segue in this scenario.  Or am I mistaken and there are some added benefit in presenting view controllers through storyboards when you aren't using UITableViews?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segues work when triggered by UI elements other than table cells.

They also work when requested in code.  For example, create a segue between two controllers (not views or controls) and it can be invoked from code anywhere in the source controller using `performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`.

Comment: With performSegueWithIdentifier, can I wire it up in the storyboard since my accessoryView (detail disclosure icon) is not being shown?  Or instead of a (1) create viewController, (2) [self presentModalViewController:], I would call [self performSegue:]?  If this is the case, then where do I create my segue?  In the examples I've seen, it's done on the storyboard vs in code so I don't know how to wire up a segue to an accessoryView to present a more detailedViewController.  Thanks!